# Consulta SQL con Query Builder de Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo esta consulta que me funciona bien

```
SELECT * FROM IGNom_Trabajador WHERE REPLACE(CODIGO, '.', '') = 12345678
```

Pero cuando trato de hacerlo con Laravel me da error, he tratado de la siguiente forma

```
DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select(DB::raw('REPLACE("CODIGO", ".", "")'))->where("CODIGO", "=", 12345678);

Employee::whereRaw('IGNom_Trabajador.*, REPLACE("CODIGO", ".", "")', '=', '12345678')->first();
```

Ninguna de estas me funciona, me retornan un objecto con la información de mi conexion a la base de datos y demas pero sin la información.

¿Como puedo traducir correctamente esta sentencia para usarla con Laravel?

Lo que me devuelve la consulta

```
C:\wamp\www\SPI\intranet\app\Http\Controllers\UserController.php:84:
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder)[344]
  protected 'query' => 
    object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder)[343]
      public 'connection' => 
        object(Illuminate\Database\SqlServerConnection)[342]
          protected 'pdo' => 
            object(Closure)[341]
              ...
          protected 'readPdo' => null
          protected 'database' => string 'NOMDB' (length=5)
          protected 'tablePrefix' => string '' (length=0)
          protected 'config' => 
            array (size=8)
              ...
          protected 'reconnector' => 
            object(Closure)[354]
              ...
          protected 'queryGrammar' => 
            object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\SqlServerGrammar)[338]
              ...
          protected 'schemaGrammar' => null
          protected 'postProcessor' => 
            object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\SqlServerProcessor)[336]
              ...
          protected 'events' => 
            object(Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher)[26]
              ...
          protected 'fetchMode' => int 5
          protected 'transactions' => int 0
          protected 'recordsModified' => boolean false
          protected 'queryLog' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'loggingQueries' => boolean false
          protected 'pretending' => boolean false
          protected 'doctrineConnection' => null
      public 'grammar' => 
        object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\SqlServerGrammar)[338]
          protected 'operators' => 
            array (size=18)
              ...
          protected 'selectComponents' => 
            array (size=12)
              ...
          protected 'tablePrefix' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'processor' => 
        object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\SqlServerProcessor)[336]
      public 'bindings' => 
        array (size=7)
          'select' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'from' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'join' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'where' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'having' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'order' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'union' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
      public 'aggregate' => null
      public 'columns' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression)[346]
              ...
      public 'distinct' => boolean false
      public 'from' => string 'IGNom_Trabajador' (length=16)
      public 'joins' => null
      public 'wheres' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
      public 'groups' => null
      public 'havings' => null
      public 'orders' => null
      public 'limit' => null
      public 'offset' => null
      public 'unions' => null
      public 'unionLimit' => null
      public 'unionOffset' => null
      public 'unionOrders' => null
      public 'lock' => null
      public 'operators' => 
        array (size=29)
          0 => string '=' (length=1)
          1 => string '<' (length=1)
          2 => string '>' (length=1)
          3 => string '<=' (length=2)
          4 => string '>=' (length=2)
          5 => string '<>' (length=2)
          6 => string '!=' (length=2)
          7 => string '<=>' (length=3)
          8 => string 'like' (length=4)
          9 => string 'like binary' (length=11)
          10 => string 'not like' (length=8)
          11 => string 'ilike' (length=5)
          12 => string '&' (length=1)
          13 => string '|' (length=1)
          14 => string '^' (length=1)
          15 => string '<<' (length=2)
          16 => string '>>' (length=2)
          17 => string 'rlike' (length=5)
          18 => string 'regexp' (length=6)
          19 => string 'not regexp' (length=10)
          20 => string '~' (length=1)
          21 => string '~*' (length=2)
          22 => string '!~' (length=2)
          23 => string '!~*' (length=3)
          24 => string 'similar to' (length=10)
          25 => string 'not similar to' (length=14)
          26 => string 'not ilike' (length=9)
          27 => string '~~*' (length=3)
          28 => string '!~~*' (length=4)
      public 'useWritePdo' => boolean false
  protected 'model' => 
    object(App\Employee)[340]
      protected 'connection' => string 'sqlsrv' (length=6)
      protected 'table' => string 'IGNom_Trabajador' (length=16)
      protected 'primaryKey' => string 'Consecutivo_Trabajador' (length=22)
      protected 'keyType' => string 'int' (length=3)
      public 'incrementing' => boolean true
      protected 'with' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'withCount' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'perPage' => int 15
      public 'exists' => boolean false
      public 'wasRecentlyCreated' => boolean false
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'original' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'changes' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'casts' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'dates' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'dateFormat' => null
      protected 'appends' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'dispatchesEvents' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'observables' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'relations' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'touches' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'timestamps' => boolean true
      protected 'hidden' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'visible' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'fillable' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'guarded' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '*' (length=1)
  protected 'eagerLoad' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'localMacros' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'onDelete' => null
  protected 'passthru' => 
    array (size=12)
      0 => string 'insert' (length=6)
      1 => string 'insertGetId' (length=11)
      2 => string 'getBindings' (length=11)
      3 => string 'toSql' (length=5)
      4 => string 'exists' (length=6)
      5 => string 'doesntExist' (length=11)
      6 => string 'count' (length=5)
      7 => string 'min' (length=3)
      8 => string 'max' (length=3)
      9 => string 'avg' (length=3)
      10 => string 'sum' (length=3)
      11 => string 'getConnection' (length=13)
  protected 'scopes' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'removedScopes' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que entrega exactamente como resultado?

Comment: Regresa un objecto con los datos de la conexion de la base de datos, la sentencia de la consulta, pero no los datos del usuario

Comment: Sí, eso lo leí en la pregunta ... pero quisiera ver realmente lo que entrega como resultado.

Comment: @Shaz Actualice la pregunta con lo que devuelve la consulta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El [`whereRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-methods) no lleva múltiples parámetros para definir la comparación como el [`where`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses).

Entiendo que `CODIGO` es el nombre de un campo, con lo cual no tiene que ir entre comillas.

La sentencia sería algo así:

```
Employee::whereRaw('REPLACE(CODIGO, ".", "") = "12345678"')->first();
```

Si `Employee` es el modelo de la tabla `IGNom_Trabajador`, no hace falta definir `SELECT IGNom_Trabajador.*`, eso se hace automáticamente.